# Rails 4 bulk updating array of models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, bulkupdate

I have an array of ActiveRecord model and I want to renumber one column and bulk update them.
Code looks like this:

```
rules = subject.email_rules.order(:number)
rules.each_with_index do |rule, index|
  rule.number = index + 1
end

EmailRule.update(rules.map(&:id), rules.map { |r| { number: r.number } })
```

But this creates N SQL statements and I would like 1, is there a way to do it?

Comment: This is not recommended as the callbacks won't be triggered. You need to treat each record one by one so the validations/callbacks are triggered.

Comment: Could you do it in SQL or do you need ruby code to run (callbacks, other logic)?

Comment: If you need to do an operation on each record then you can't avoid this.  If you had a way to predict what each number should be then you can avoid instantiating each object which is what is taking up the bulk of your time.

Comment: No, I dont need any other code to run. This is the only callback in the model and its after_destroy.

Comment: @JiříVojta in that case you can do it in pure SQL. see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using postgres you can use `row_number` and the somewhat strange looking **UPDATE/FROM** construct. This is the basic version:

```
UPDATE email_rules target 
SET number = src.idx
FROM (
  SELECT 
    email_rules.id,
    row_number() OVER () as idx
    FROM email_rules
) src
WHERE src.id = target.id
```

You might need to scope this on a `subject` and of course include the order by number which could look like this:

```
UPDATE email_rules target 
SET number = src.idx
FROM (
  SELECT 
    email_rules.id,
    row_number() OVER (partition by subject_id) as idx
    FROM email_rules
    ORDER BY number ASC
) src
WHERE src.id = target.id
```

(assuming `subject_id` is the foreign key that associates subjects/email_rules)

Comment: I'm testing this right now and it seems to be shuffling the numbers which I dont want. I dont do much SQL so I cant see why is that happening, can you?

Comment: Shuffling how? Can you give me a sample?

as far as I can tell you want to give every `EmailRule` of a `Subject` a new `number` which should start at 1 and count upwards. `EmailRule` are sorted by existing `number`. 

This will not change the order of the `EmailSubject` (when sorting by `number`) but will remove gaps (1, 2, 5, 6 => 1,2,3,4) and make sure the `number` starts at 1 (4,5,6,7 => 1,2,3,4).

Comment: Seems to pe problem in our app, not in your code, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

One alternative to you is to put all interaction in a transaction and it will at least make one single commit at the end, making it way faster.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  ...
end
```

Comment: Wrapping it in a transaction helps. Also disabling the logger and all the validations might help. But IMHO this should be possible in pure SQL.